# CakePHP 2.1 + AJAX Search / JsHelper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I try to create an Ajax search with CakePHP using the JsHelper. The Ajax request triggers but it never returns values:

Search form (find_entries.ctp):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Entry');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title', array('div' => false, 'empty', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Search'));?>

<?php echo $this->Js->submit('Upload', array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#checking')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#checking')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#choose_options')
    )
;?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Controller:

```
public function find_entries(){
    if(!empty($this->request->data)){

            $entries = $this->Entry->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Entry.title' => $this->request->data['Entry']['title);    
    $this->set('entries', $entries);
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
    $this->render('entries', 'ajax');   
    }
    }

}
```

Partial to render (entries.ctp)

```
<div id="entries">

<?php foreach ($entries as $entry) :?>

    <?php echo $entry['Entry']['title']; ?>

<?php endforeach ;?>
```

What goes wrong here? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you created any div tag with id `choose_options` to render the ajax result? If not create a div tag like this in the view file.

```
<div id="choose_options"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am quite an egg. I forgot to remove the 'entries' div from the view file. after that it worked.